# Rails 5.2 | Select2 Multiple Comma Seperated Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I'm new to Rails and I'm running in circles trying to implement a Select2 input with multiple selections. I've read the solutions on StackOverflow and none of them helped me, which typically means I'm doing something unusually wrong.

When I'm submitting my form it sends my **federation_list** parameter multiple times with different values (*in headers*):

`event[federation_list]: WDC`

`event[federation_list]: WDSF`

I need all of the values in one Federation parameter seperated by a comma, that I can then split in my controller.

I've tried adding `name: "federation_list[]"` as it says in the Select2 documentation, but my form_with overwrites it so it loses the brackets.

**Updated! I figured out the solution and this is my working code:**

**select2_initializer.js**

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $( "#event_federation_list" ).select2({
        theme: "bootstrap",
    multiple: true,
    placeholder: 'Select Federation(s)',
    width: 'style'
    }).val('').trigger('change');
});
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <%= form.label :federation_list, value: "Federations", class: "form-label" %>
      <%= form.select :federation_list, options_from_collection_for_select(Federation.all, :id, :name, {:selected => @event.federations.map(&:id)}), {}, { multiple: true } %>
</div>
```

The :selected makes the selected options appear when the user edits the form.

**event.rb**

```
def federation_list
    self.federations.map(&:name).join(', ')
end

def federation_list=(names)
    self.federations = names.split(',').map do |n|
        Federation.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
    end
end
```

If it is relevant information my Event **has_many:** Federations, **through:** Event_Federations.

[GitHub rep](https://github.com/Curting/mydanceplan)

I ended up going with Selectize instead of Select2, but the solution still holds true for Select2.

And then I wrote this piece of code in my **event.rb**:

```
def federation_list
    self.federations.map(&:name).join(', ')
  end

  def federation_list=(ids)
    self.federations = ids.reject!(&:empty?).map do |id|
      Federation.where(id: id).first
      # Use .first_or_create! to let the user add new objects
    end
  end
```

I used **SteveTurczyns** advise and added **federation_list: []** in my strong params.

And that works!

Comment: Is that the correct repo?  There's no Federation or EventFederation models.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, @SteveTurczyn. I forgot to push it up to Git. I just pushed it up on its own Federation branch. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: And there's still no Federation or EventFederation models, nor does the above code appear.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn - I have no idea why the files weren't added to my commit before. I've double checked and they're there now at https://github.com/Curting/mydanceplan/tree/federation. Sorry for the inconvinience!

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this is your only problem but a definite problem is that strong parameters require that you explicitly specify if a model parameter is an array.

Instead of

```
  params.require(:event).permit(:title, :country, 
    :city, :start_date, :end_date, :published_at, :user_id,
    :federation_list)
```

You should have

```
  params.require(:event).permit(:title, :country, 
    :city, :start_date, :end_date, :published_at, :user_id,
    federation_list: [])
```

Comment: Thank you! You put me in the right direction. I'll describe my solution below.